# How to build a express api in es6 script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6

I use the express generator build a no-view rest api first.
Then I change the whole things to es6 script and let it compile by babel.

When I enter the localhost after the changes, it says:

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

And I found out it's because of this part of code.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

The error disappear when I change the res.render to res.json

I just wondering do I have to assign a view engine if I use the babel to compile my project? Even It's a no view api?

Comment: I'm confused why you specifically mention `es6`, since the code you've shown has no es6 or later "syntax" to it - that would run in an `es5` environment quite happily  - so, my question is, what does `es6` have to do with anything?

Comment: @Bravo Because the problem is not about the es6 scripts. And my question is after the  compilation of babel. It give me a warning "No default engine was specified and no extension was provided". So do I have to assign a view engine for the babel compilation of a es6 project?

Comment: when you "change the whole things to es6 script" (whatever that means) was part of the changes you made to use `res.render` - or were you using `res.render` before you changed your code use the 7 year old javascript spec in some place you haven't even shown?

Comment: `do I have to assign a view engine for the babel compilation of a es6 project?` no, you have to set up a view engine if you want to use res.render - regardless of which flavour scripting

Answer (score 0):

To use views on express you need to configure it to use some engine (pug, ejs, handlebars), refer to the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html) to know how it works.

The error that you mentioned

> No default engine was specified and no extension was provided

means that you didn't configure any view engine, also, the template file is missing the extension, (i.g. index.pug).

When you use `res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });` you are calling the view engine to render the template `index` and passing some values to use in it `{ title: 'Express' }`, the result is a HTML content.

On other hand, when you use `res.json({ title: 'Express' })` you are returning a `json` object, that's the difference.

Here is the link to the documentation of each one:

[res.render](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.render)

[res.json](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.json)